# Whitespace Problems With Script and Variables

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to beat my head against the syntax of this. I'm getting problems with whitespaces and I can't see if there's a better way to do this.

```
vardir=/home/user
cd $vardir
for i in $(ls "$vardir") ; do
timestamp="$(stat -c %Y $i)"
echo "$i"
echo "$timestamp"

done
```

Result is similar no matter where I quote and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
stat: cannot stat ‘Temporary’: No such file or directory
Temporary

stat: cannot stat ‘Items’: No such file or directory
Items
```

My goal is I want to grab the timestamps off of backup directories and `touch` the current ones to restore the original modified dates.

Comment: http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#ls

Comment: That's a good link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As other people said before me: [**Don’t parse the output of `ls`!**](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/47852)

Why not simply:

```
stat --printf='%y\t%n\n' -- *
```

If you want to do something with each file name and time stamp, `read` the output of `stat` like this:

```
stat --printf='%y\t%n\0' -- * | \
while IFS=$'\t' read -rd '' timestamp i; do
    echo "filename: ${i}, timestamp: ${timestamp}"
done
```

No need to spawn a new `stat` process for every file, which you'll notice as soon as you spawn a few hundred processes for a few hundred files.

For more complicated matches than simple globbing, I recommend `find` with a suitable `-printf` option.

*Edit:* As per the comments to this answer, I found out that OP actually wants to copy the modification time stamps from files of one directory to another. This is what I suggest:

```
for f in /source/dir/*; do
    touch -c -r "${f}" "/dest/dir/${f##*/}"
done
```

This takes all entries from `/source/dir` as time stamp references (`-r`) for entries of the same file name in `/dest/dir` without creating new files that don't exist in `/dest/dir` yet (`-c`).

Comment: David, thanks. This was clever as hell and did what it needed to as quick as anything. It was trivial to change this to touch -d with a second line for echo in the while loop and this accomplished my goal very simply.

Comment: If you want to want to `touch` a file with the modification time of another, you should use `touch -r [REFERENCE FILE] [FILES TO TOUCH]` instead of an equivalent of `touch -d "$(stat -c %y [REFERENCE FILE])" [FILES TO TOUCH]`.

Comment: Ugh. So I simply could have done

`touch -r /source/dir/* /dest/dir/*`

with no script.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. `touch -r /source/dir/* /dest/dir/*` applies the modification time of the first match of `/source/dir/*` to all the other matches of `/source/dir/*` and `/dest/dir/*`. What you want is probably something like my update to the answer.

Comment: I have a lot to learn! Thanks for your very excellent answers.

Answer (score 4):

Do not parse the output of `ls`, use a glob:

```
for i in * ; do
```

Also, quote the variables that might contain spaces:

```
    timestamp=$(stat -c %y "$i")
```